# how do i do two partitions but in between draw a vertical line in css

Tags: html, css, partitioning

i'm trying to make two partitions one part contain image and another part contain text. i have provided image like how i want to make it but sorry i can't provide image over here because of less than 10 reputation i have it need at least 10 reputation to post image here so please go to the image link which is provided in comment box.also i have provided my code what i have tried. so please can anyone help by providing any example. and i'm trying to make layout like this what i have already provided in the comment box please check that from comment box and i'm really new in Cascading Style Sheets so please help me out. thanks in advance.

**My HTML so far:**

```
<div class = "layer5 main">
    <h1>Features</h1>
    <DIV style="width: 50%; border-right: solid 2px lightgreen">
    </DIV>
</div>
```

[Here](http://%20ibb.co/jxjyJv) is what I'm trying to make.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/archan/1zut89fo) is what I have so far.

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: Layout link what i'm trying to make https://ibb.co/jxjyJv and my code link what i have done https://jsfiddle.net/archan/1zut89fo/

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question

Comment: it is not duplicate my question is different please read carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some container, then add 2 elements (blocks or table cells) in it. Style it. That's all.

There's an easy solution with vertical align.

```css
.layer5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
}

.image,
.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0px solid tomato;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
}

.text {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  width: 198px;
  
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer5 main">
  <h1>Features</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://www.enterprise.com/content/dam/global-vehicle-images/cars/FORD_FOCU_2012-1.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati voluptas accusamus quidem officia. Provident consectetur ab nulla placeat fuga iusto, cumque voluptatem magnam veniam minus incidunt unde quae error labore?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but i want add some margin on the right side of image i mean between image and line i want some space or gap https://jsfiddle.net/8fb03gu0/ so how do i do that ?

Comment: You added a background image and not as an element, as in my example. Change it. Then you can set margins to the image.

Comment: mate why you removed the background image i have restrictions to use only background images that's why i have used there so please without removing bg image i'm expecting and sure i will give vote but still i didn't get what i'm expecting and middle line is also too high look i'm expecting like this https://ibb.co/mLs8mF please refer this.

Comment: that middle line is i'm expecting as per the sentence height not too high as like image

Comment: For attribute `.feat1` add `background-position: right 30px center;` where `30px` is a position form right side of background, and `background-repeat: no-repeat;`. That's all you need, I think.

Comment: yeah that's good bro but please tell me how to decrease the height of side border( vertical line).

Comment: bro please help i have tried through by adding div tags and make them absolute positioning then some height reduced but not all i want. please anyone help me out guys

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/8fb03gu0/8/) your project with comments what I added and removed. Now you can set class `.line` whatewer you want.

Comment: thanks a lot bro you deserve up vote plus high ratting. if suppose i will need your help in future then how should i communicate with you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.layer5
{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.firstSection{float:left;width:45%;}
.secondSection{float:left;width:45%;}
.seprator{width: 5%; border-right: solid 2px lightgreen;height:25px;float:left;}
```

```html
<div class = "layer5 main">
    <div class='firstSection'>Features1</div>
    <div class='seprator'></div>
    <div class='secondSection'>Features2</div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but i want add some margin on the right side of image i mean between image and line i want some space or gap https://jsfiddle.net/8fb03gu0/ so how do i do that ?

Comment: You can use float attribute and then use padding-right for have space between two div
 https://jsfiddle.net/8fb03gu0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```css
.layer5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  display: block;
}

#imgdiv img {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}

#textdiv p {
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#textdiv2 p {
  float: left;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 50px;
  border-left: none
}

#imgdiv2 img {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer5 main">
  <h1>Features</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="imgdiv">
      <img src="http://www.dl.21tech.ir/img-upload/2017/3/95121201.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="textdiv">
      <p>This is the text part.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="imgdiv2">
      <img src="http://www.dl.21tech.ir/img-upload/2017/3/95121201.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="textdiv2">
      <p>This is the text part.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah but i want add some margin on the right side of image i mean between image and line i want some space or gap https://jsfiddle.net/8fb03gu0/ so how do i do that ?

Comment: @ArchanGhatpande Lower `padding-left` in `#textdiv p` and `padding-right` in `#textdiv2 p`, set them for example to `30px`.